# HTML Form not submitting, it is just refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that is submitting an image to be cropped on the server, the image can be uploaded from the end users computer or can be a screenshot from in-game that automatically gets uploaded and then they get redirected to the form that auto populates with their image. I cannot get the form to submit when going the in-game route. Instead it refreshes the page losing all data. Here is a test with pre-loaded data. [Click Me!](http://play.unidentifiedgaming.net:8080/learning/imagecropper/index.php?mapname=deathrun_industrial&user=FusionLord&uploaded=true)

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<style>
    <?php include 'styles/style.css'; ?>
    <?php include 'scripts/cropper/cropper.css' ?>
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    <?php include 'scripts/cropper/cropper.js'; ?>
    <?php include 'scripts/controller.js' ?>
</script>
<?php
    $_mapName = isset($_GET["mapname"]) ? $_GET["mapname"] : "";
    $_userName = isset($_GET["user"]) ? $_GET["user"] : "";
    $_uploaded = isset($_GET["uploaded"]) ? $_GET["uploaded"] : "false";
    $_image = "";
    if (strtolower($_uploaded) == "true") {
        $_image = "./images/tmp/" . $_userName . ".png";
    }
?>
<body>
<div id="float_left_static" class="border">
    Want to vote for a map image? <br>
    <a href="vote.php">Click here!</a>
</div>
<div id="float_center" class="border">
        <div id="float_center">
            <p style="text-align: center">So you have a screen shot and you thing it worthy as the maps image?<br>
                Well upload, crop, and submit it and the community will vote on it.
            </p>
            <form action="crop.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="mapName">Map Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="mapName" id="mapName"
                                   value="<?php echo $_mapName; ?>" <?php echo (isset($_mapName) && $_mapName != "") ? "readonly" : ""; ?>>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="file">Map Image:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="populateImage(this)">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userName">Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName"
                                   value="<?php echo $_userName; ?>" <?php echo (isset($_userName) && $_userName != "") ? "readonly" : ""; ?>>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="submit">Submit:</label>
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload and Crop">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="x" id="x" />
                <input type="hidden" name="y" id="y" readonly/>
                <input type="hidden" name="width" id="width" />
                <input type="hidden" name="height" id="height" />
                <input type="hidden" name="uploaded" value="<?php echo strtolower($_uploaded); ?>"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    <img id="cropper" width="100%" src="<?php echo $_image; ?>"/>
    <?php
        if ($_image != "") {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> refreshCropper(); </script>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: In your form you have `method="post"` but you're using `$_GET` in your php.

Comment: If you had PHP error reporting turned on you would have figured this out immediately

Comment: @pottedmeat7 it works fine without the parameters and adding a backslash changes nothing other than trying to find the crop.php in the root dir.

Comment: @DiddleDot notice the action is a different php file.

Comment: you have to use $_FILES array to get uploaded file data.

Comment: @RavinderReddy the file is already uploaded and I'm not using the input[type=file] in this example.

Comment: Turns out it was an error in the Crop.php I was not checking to see if the file was preuploaded and was using the file that wasn't there as a fail safe I was sending the end user back to the original page.